# Using FMA Alchemy as the basis of magic in a fate system

Tags: fate, alchemy

What rules would need to change/be added to use the concept of alchemy from full metal alchemist in an urban magic game using the FATE system.

Are there any synthesized gaming discussions for how the mechanics of FMA alchemy works?

Comment: Which FMA alchemy system are we talking? Original Anime or Manga/FMA Brotherhood? Because the latter has the whole problem of Alcahistory to deal with.

Comment: My nine year old wants you all to know an answer to this would be "awesome."

Comment: I'd prefer FMA Brotherhood, as I'm 30 episodes in, but yes, the "eastern/western" split seems... different. For a first pass, a description/condensation of the understanding/destruction/creation loop would be good.

Comment: @mxyzplk If we find a good answer, I may just have to test the answer over in The Back Room. I'd love to have a knowledgeable and informed playtester, if your nine your old wants to participate. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a baseline, you have a few ethical and absolute rules:

1. You must work with an equal amount of material.
2. You cannot transmute gold.
3. You cannot transmute humans.

2 & 3 seem more ethical limitations, with 1 being the only absolute limitation we are shown.

But other than that, though each alchemist seems to focus on his own interests, it seems a pretty wide open magic system.

A couple of threads on FMA adaptions:

1. [RPG.NET discussion](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?301021-Full-Metal-Alchemist-is-there-an-RPG&p=6679771#post6679771)
2. [Mythweavers discussion](http://www.myth-weavers.com/showthread.php?t=152918)
3. [GURPS discussion](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?s=0eff65ec11c6b095b76318581a63dbd3&t=80034)
4. [FMA Adaptation for FU RPG](http://snipersnake.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/a-bit-of-free-full-metal-alchemist/) ([Direct Link to PDF](http://www.rattlesnakegames.com/FU%20Metal%20Alchemist.pdf))

With that in mind, I'd take a page from the Dresden Files RPG., having a Q&D version of alchemy, and a ritual version.  The Q&D version would require a focus, i.e. `YS256`.  Perhaps even limit Q&D to 'rotes', though base the rotes on the element more than the actual expression of the rote, i.e. instead of fire ball, an offensive 4 shift use of fire.  Though for more practiced Alchemists, this might be very limiting compared to the source media.  The largest limitation- the transmutation of like matter- I'd handle in aspects, i.e the template/high concept would mention something about alchemy, which can be compelled in relation to available matter.

Comment: Well 3 is a limitation, but the series bends it around a bit. The first time the Elric brothers try Human alchemy **bad things happen**. Father can do it just fine, presumably since he's got a philsopher's stone (well...several actually), and Alcahistory can use it for medicine, but is more limited in the other things it can do. But it seems in standard Almestrian Alchemy it is a fairly hard limitation because of the severe consequences.

Comment: That's true... though it does seem to be a combination of ethics/warning, as it *can* be done (and without mishap under the right circumstances/story need).  So system-wise, that would be tough to model, which was why I sort of glossed over it... :-/